# scraping xml/javascript table with R

Tags: javascript, r, scrape

I want to scrape a table like this http://www.oddsportal.com//hockey/usa/nhl/carolina-hurricanes-ottawa-senators-80YZhBGC/
I'd want to scrape the bookmakers and the odds. The problem is I don't know what kind of a table that is nor how to scrape it.

These threads might be able to help me ([Scraping javascript with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249940/scraping-javascript-with-r) or [What type of HTML table is this and what type of webscraping techniques can you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026410/what-type-of-html-table-is-this-and-what-type-of-webscraping-techniques-can-you)) but I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or better yet give instructions here.

So what kind of a table is that odds table, is it possible to scrape it with R and if so, how?

Edit:
I should have been more clear. I have scraped data with R for some time now and probably dont need help with basics. After further inspection that table is indeed Javascript and that is the problem and what I need help with

Comment: Take a look at [Scraping html tables into R data frames using the XML package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package)

Comment: I have read that thread pretty extensively but it hasn't helped me with scraping that specific table. I have scraped several other tables easily with those instructions. If I for example read the url with tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl), the main odds table is not there. I also can't find the figures if I inspect the oddsportal source closely, which isn't the case in the brazil wikipedia table that is used in the link you provided. I'm afraid I might need more help

Comment: Use a javascript/web dev debugger to see what requests the page is making - it might just be a json data request and no scraping is needed, your R can just get the JSON data directly. Maybe. Its just slow and horrible for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Selenium and [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) to get the relevant data:

```
library(RSelenium)
appURL <- "http://www.oddsportal.com//hockey/usa/nhl/carolina-hurricanes-ottawa-senators-80YZhBGC"
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(appURL)
tblSource <- remDr$executeScript("return tbls[0].outerHTML;")[[1]]
readHTMLTable(tblSource)
> readHTMLTable(tblSource)
$`NULL`
Bookmakers    1    X    2 Payout 
1   Â bet-at-homeÂ Â 2.25 3.80 2.60  91.6% 
2        Â bet365Â Â 2.29 3.79 2.64  92.7% 
3       Â BetssonÂ Â 2.35 3.75 2.65  93.5% 
4          Â bwinÂ Â 2.30 3.75 2.70  93.3% 
5   Â MarathonBetÂ Â 2.35 3.80 2.78  95.4% 
6      Â TitanbetÂ Â 2.30 3.95 2.50  91.9% 
7       Â TonyBetÂ Â 2.35 3.70 2.70  93.8% 
8        Â UnibetÂ Â 2.35 3.85 2.60  93.5% 
9  Â William HillÂ Â 2.30 3.90 2.50  91.6% 
10       Â WinnerÂ Â 2.30 3.95 2.50  91.9% 
11       Â youwinÂ Â 2.40 3.75 2.55  93.0%
```

Comment: thank you a lot! after reading this http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html and some trial and error this worked very well! I'm sure I could figure this out with callback calls but this was obviously much easier for me.

Comment: @jdharrison Do you care to explain how to find that the table was tbls[0].outerHTML?

Comment: `tbls[0].outerHTML` gets the HTML of the first table node. `readHTMLTable` can process HTML representing a table node.

Answer (score 2):

The "bookies" data comes from a request for a javascript callback resource:

```
GET /x/bookies-140619144601-1403252087.js HTTP/1.1
Host: rb.oddsportal.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.oddsportal.com//hockey/usa/nhl/carolina-hurricanes-ottawa-senators-80YZhBGC/
Connection: keep-alive
```

it returns a callback resource that has the bookie info, but no odds. There are other callback AJAX calls for the data, but you'll have to dig.

[Burp Proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) is a great way to see the URI calls, but the DOM inspection (as @Spacedman suggested) should always be your first line of investigation.