# Exporting citation of a journal article using R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, scrape

I want R to:

1. Go [THIS](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/documentcitationdownload?publicationDoi=10.1002/(ISSN)1532-2890&doi=10.1002/asi.21577&type=journal) page.
2. Select "Bibtex" as Format, "Citation and Abstract" for "Export type".
3. Press "Submit" and download the citation file to a designated folder.

Is it possible? How can I do that with R? (I don't know JavaScript and I couldn't understand earlier topics much related to this issue. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249940/scraping-javascript-with-r), [2](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-choose-a-button-and-scrape-the-website-data-td4447100.html), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330393/scraping-javascript-generated-data))

Eventually, I want to download all bibtex (and possibly Endnote) citations of a journal (for example [THIS](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)2330-1643/issues) journal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fake a form submission with the `httr` package. For this request you could do

```
values <- list(
    doi = "10.1002%2Fasi.21577",
    fileFormat = "BIBTEX",
    hasAbstract = "CITATION_AND_ABSTRACT"
)

library(httr)
url <- "http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/documentcitationdownloadformsubmit"
rr <- POST(url=url, body=values, encode="form")
content(rr, "text")
# [1] "﻿@article {ASI:ASI21577,\nauthor = {Callahan, Ewa S. ...
```

Comment: If you don't want t it to be a stream you will need something like this: `val <-readLines(textConnection(content(rr, "text")))`

Answer (score 5):

I think `rcrossref` https://github.com/ropensci/rcrossref#citation-search can help you here, e.g.,

```
install.packages("rcrossref")
library("rcrossref")    

cat(cr_cn(dois = "10.1126/science.169.3946.635", format = "bibtex"))
#> @article{Frank_1970,
#>  doi = {10.1126/science.169.3946.635},
#>  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.169.3946.635},
#>  year = 1970,
#>  month = {aug},
#>  publisher = {American Association for the Advancement of Science ({AAAS})},
#>  volume = {169},
#>  number = {3946},
#>  pages = {635--641},
#>  author = {H. S. Frank},
#>  title = {The Structure of Ordinary Water: New data and interpretations are yielding new insights     into this fascinating substance},
#>  journal = {Science}
#> }
```

With this you just need the DOI's. There are other functions in the package to search for articles and get DOIs by publisher, etc.

hope that helps

Comment: im the maintainer of `rcrossref` - let me know if you have any questions on it

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out this. I didn't know the existence of it. I'm guessing this will not get the abstract of an article given the DOI, right?